# Video onclick switch from place

Tags: javascript, php

If you scroll down on the [page](http://devtel.nl/cellroframe/test/) there are 4 video's. Iam trying to make that if you click on one of the small video's the video moves up to the big section. If you click on a small video it send you to YouTube.

You will see some variables in the code those are in a other file.

Here is my code:

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: '<?php echo $videoTop; ;?>',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        }
    });
}
$('.video').on('click',function(){
    $('.video').removeClass('overlay');
});
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    $('.video').click(function() {
        event.target.playVideo();
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#player').hide();
    $('#play_vid').click(function() {
        $('#player').show();
        $('#play_vid').hide();
    });
});

$('#image_id').click(function() {
  $("#some_id iframe").attr('src', $("#some_id iframe", parent).attr('src') + '?autoplay=1'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5" id="videos">
<div class="video overlay" autoplay=1>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="play_vid" style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $overlayImage;?>')"></div>
</div>
    <h5><?php echo $video_h; ?></h5>
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $vid1;?>" class="video"><img src="images/<?php echo $vidImg1;?>" alt="thumb"/></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $vid2;?>" class="video"><img src="images/<?php echo $vidImg2;?>" alt="thumb"/></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $vid3;?>" class="video"><img src="images/<?php echo $vidImg3;?>" alt="thumb"/></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me out with this one?

Comment: Help you how?  What exactly is your question?  What is the result of your current code and how does that differ from what you want?  Most people (myself included) are not going to visit a random external site to understand what's going on.

Comment: I had to short in the code because I had to mutch code. Currently the video's are next to each other and there is one big section with 1 video. If you click one of those video's you go straight to YouTube and thats not what I want. If you click on a small video it needs to appear in the big section.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried to get that to happen?  Please make it clear in your question what code is supposed to do "If you click on a small video it needs to appear in the big section".

Answer (score 0):

You have to `preventDefault()` of the click... The small videos are links to youtube, so by default the browser will navigate to the link. In this case you don't want to navigate there, you want to change the highlighted video.

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

[[Source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
$('.video').click(function(event) {

  // event is the action of the click
  event.preventDefault();

  // run your code to display the code into the "larger" box
  renderVideo();

});
```

Whenever you are performing an action (e.g. submitting a form) you can use `event.preventDefault()` to alter the browser's behavior.